# how to set bgimage differ in all screen of each tab in android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

how to set differ back ground image in each Activity of each tab ?

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: thanx but i want different bg image of activity of each image